# Light rays from a point source, reflected from a searchlight mirror, are directed as a parallel beam. What surface of revolution is the mirror?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

The question comes from GN Berman, and hints given are as follows:

"Paraboloid of revolution.

Let the plane $Oxy$ be a meridian plane of the mirror surface, the required line lies in this plane. The needed differential equation is derived by equating the tangents of the angles of incidence and reflection expressed in terms of $x$, $y$, $y^\prime$."

Comment: Search for parabolic mirror

Comment: How hard is it to type the text of the photo into the question box so that it comes out consistent with the other text of this site and not sideways?

Comment: As well, photos of text aren’t searchable.

Comment: The problem is a little vague, is it like this imagin https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parabolic_reflector#/media/File:Focus-balanced_parabolic_reflector.svg

Comment: Thank you for the link. It further led me to the geometric proof. But G N Berman asks for a calculus proof, using maxima minima concept.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

From the diagram,
$$
\tan(\theta)=\frac xy\tag{1}
$$
and
$$
\tan(\theta/2)=-\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x}\tag{2}
$$
Using the formula for $\tan(2\theta)$, we get
$$
\frac xy=\frac{-2\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x}}{1-\left(\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x}\right)^2}\tag{3}
$$
Equation $(2)$ is satisfied by $y=ax^2-b$, where
$$
\begin{align}
\frac{x}{ax^2-b}
&=\frac{-4ax}{1-4a^2x^2}\\
&=\frac{x}{ax^2-\frac1{4a}}\tag{4}
\end{align}
$$
Therefore, $b=\frac1{4a}$. That is,
$$
y=ax^2-\frac1{4a}\tag{5}
$$